# The thing that adds a trait to another thing?

Tags: single-word-requests

Say A does something to B that causes B to have an additional trait.

For example, A cooks B to add the trait "cooked" to B; A damages B to add the trait "damaged"; or A hugs B to add "hugged"; etc. as in "B is cooked/damaged/hugged".

What is a word to describe A?  ...I'm thinking "applicator"?  The main effect that I'm going for is that A is adding something new to B's list of adjectives.

EDIT: the word for the action that A takes, ie. "drive", needn't be the root word for the trait that B is given, ie. "driven", which is a valid interpretation of how I posed the question.  I am, however, looking for the general term, just to clarify :D

Comment: It doesn't always work like that. You can ***drive*** your son to school every day, but this may never cause him to acquire the trait of being ***driven** [to achieve his objectives]*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I don't think OP is suggesting it would work with every verb, no need to complicate things!

Comment: @Mynamite: The number of contexts where it doesn't apply are so tiny compared to the number where it *does* that I don't think I've significantly enlarged the scope here. I've no idea if there's a specific term for *using past participle of "active/agent" verb to adjectivally describe "post-action" state of "patient" noun*, but even if there *is*, it could probably be usefully contrasted with cases where that doesn't apply. I've also no idea whether *a rusted bolt* counts, since although it's been "acted upon", there is no "agent" A who actually rusted it.

Comment: ...looking again at the OP's examples, I'm having difficulty imagining in what circumstances you might refer to *a hugged B*, after *A* hugs *B*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think it's the quality of having been hugged rather than referring to someone as a 'hugged' person. In any case, OP is asking for a word for person A, not adjectives for person B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If A is causing a change to B's description, A is *[modifying](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/modify)* B, which makes A a ***modifier***.

(Perhaps unfortunately, this term can also be used for the traits themselves; they are modifiers to the word or term B.)

Comment: ahh, you beat me by a hair. good job.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to make something up for you: **agent of change**.  It might not be the final term you end up with, but I hope it at least gets you closer.

(I don't think *modifier* does what you've asked for because it's not active enough.)

Answer (score 0):

A thing that changes something could be said to be a **modifier**, and I think that adding a trait would constitute a change. More data and I may be able to find a better term.